# Python Widget - How made this plot?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, widget

I know that if I want plot/print something with the widget, i should use the following code:

```
interact(function,variable=(1,3))
```

Now I am facing a problem. Is it possible create a widget that have as input two arrays? for example, consider the case when:

```
a= np.linspace(1,2,100)
b= np.linspace(3,4,100)
```

Is it possible see the behaviour of a function, with two different arrays (e.g. switch from the interval *a*, to the interval *b*)?
Below I have tried something, but it does not works..

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from __future__ import print_function
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets
a= np.linspace(1,2,100)
b= np.linspace(3,4,100)
def test(array,constant):
    f = []
    for x in array:
        f.append(x**2+constant*x)
    plt.plot(f)
    plt.show()
    return f
interact(test,array=(a,b),constant=(1,5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from __future__ import print_function
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets


xs = {"a": np.linspace(1, 2, 100), "b": np.linspace(3, 4, 100)}

def test(constant, array):

    x = xs[array] 
    f = x**2*constant*x
    plt.plot(x, f)
    plt.show()

interact(test, array=xs.keys(), constant=(1,5))
```

It will create a widget with a slider to control the `constant` value and a pull down menu to select one of the two arrays.